# Function not returning - program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --

Tags: mips

Function is not returning and giving me the error - program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --. This is from the tutorial MIPS Tutorial 15 Introduction to Function Youtube series by Amell Peralta. Using the Mars simulator and on Windows OS.

Stepping through the program and somehow the  $ra register is holding the address of the instruction li $v0 1 and not addi $s0, $zero, 5 too. The PC register is holding an address passed the end of the program address too.

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "Hi, everybody. \nMy bane is Amell.\n"
.text
main:
    jal displayMessage 

    addi $s0, $zero, 5

    li $v0, 1
    add $a0, $zero, $s0
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

displayMessage:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

Expected:
Hi, everybody. My name is Amell! \n 5.

Actual: Hi, everybody. My name is Amell!

Comment: _"and somehow the $ra register is holding the address of the instruction li $v0 1"_ Sounds to me like you had delayed branch slots enabled in the simulator. What you describe is how an actual MIPS CPU would behave, but when people use simulators like SPIM/MARS they often disable delayed branching, perhaps because it's seen as an unnecessary burden on students.

Comment: Nice tip!! Just disabled delayed branching and my program works.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Java SE Runtime Environment 8u201 instead and not 8u202 somehow fixed the issue.